# Why does ADO recordset return more records than the underlying Access query

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ado

I have a table `Table1` in Access 2016 (Primary Key = `Code`) with the following values:

```
=====+=============
Code + Name
=====+=============
A1   | AU All
A2   | AU Large
A3   | AU Size
A4   | Unassigned
=====+=============
```

And I have a query, `Query1` defined as:

```
SELECT Table1.Code
FROM Table1
WHERE (((Table1.Name) Not Like "AU *"));
```

In Access, the query returns 1 record, as expected:

```
Code
======
A4
======
```

But, when I open the query using ADO 2.8 or 6.1, using this code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub test()
  Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
  Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

  With rst
    .Open "Query1", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
    Do While Not .EOF
      Debug.Print .Fields("Code").Value
      .MoveNext
    Loop
    Debug.Print "Record Count : " & .RecordCount
    .Close
  End With

End Sub
```

All 4 records are returned, as evidenced by the debug output:

```
A1
A2
A3
A4
Record Count : 4
```

Why am I getting different results?

Comment: change the wild card character from * to %

Comment: @nazark, it's MS Access, not SQL server!

Comment: Try to replace the name of query with it's content! Let me know what happens.

Comment: You missunderstood what i was trying to tell you. You have to pass `SELECT Table1.Code FROM Table1 WHERE (((Table1.Name) Not Like "AU *"));` as first parameter of `Open` method for ADO.Recodset, instead of `Query1`!

Comment: @MaciejLos It makes no difference whether the source is a query name, or the underlying SQL. The change of wildcard from `*` to `%` in the query, or in a SQL string *does* produce the expected results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try wild card character from * to % as

```
  .Open "SELECT Table1.Code FROM Table1 
WHERE (((Table1.Name) Not Like 'AU %'))", 
CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
```

see for more [details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844937.aspx)

Comment: You're right, changing the wildcard to `%` in the underlying query, or specifying the query in SQL (and using the `%` wildcard in the ADO call both produce the expected output. The wildcards seem to remind me of why I've made conscious decisions in the past to use DAO when working *within* Access...

Comment: You can also consider using `ALIKE` instead of `LIKE` in your saved queries if you want more consistent behavior between internal and external execution of them.

Comment: Thanks @GordThompson, I went with the `ALiKE` approach, which I didn't know even existed until your comment. How far back does that work in Access expressions?